Installing EspoCRM on Ubuntu with Enginx and CloudPanel
I have installed EspoCRM on my VPS that runs on Ubuntu, Nginx and CloudPanel.
I followed the Enginx configuration intructions for EspoCRM in the link below
https://docs.espocrm.com/administration/nginx-server-configuration/
The installation was completed successfully, however when I visit my website it is showing me a Bad Server Response Error. Below is the configuration file that I placed in the vHost Editor of CloudPanel.
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  {{ssl_certificate_key}}
  {{ssl_certificate}}
  server_name crm.mysite.net;
  #{{root}}
  root /home/icon-crm/htdocs/crm.mysite.net; # path to public dir

  {{nginx_access_log}}
  {{nginx_error_log}}

  if ($scheme != "https") {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$uri permanent;
  }

  location ~ /.well-known {
    auth_basic off;
    allow all;
  }

  {{settings}}

  location / {
    {{varnish_proxy_pass}}
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_hide_header X-Varnish;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_connect_timeout      720;
    proxy_send_timeout         720;
    proxy_read_timeout         720;
    proxy_buffer_size          128k;
    proxy_buffers              4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size    256k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
  }

  location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|gz|svg|svgz|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|eot|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|webp|zip|swf|map)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
    expires max;
    access_log off;
  }

  if (-f $request_filename) {
    break;
  }
}

server {
  listen 8080;
  listen [::]:8080;
  server_name crm.mysite.net;
  #{{root}}
  root /home/icon-crm/htdocs/crm.mysite.net/public; # path to public dir

  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  index index.php index.html;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS "on";
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT 443;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:{{php_fpm_port}};
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "{{php_settings}}";
  }

  if (-f $request_filename) {
    break;
  }
}

#Start of EspoCRM Block *************************************************************

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    
    server_name crm.mysite.net; # domain name
    charset utf-8;
    index index.html index.php;
    client_max_body_size 50M;
    keepalive_timeout 300;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    server_tokens off;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;

    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/json;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_comp_level 9;


    #root /home/icon-crm/htdocs/crm.mysite.net/public; # path to public dir
        

    location /client {
        root /home/icon-crm/htdocs/crm.mysite.net/; # path to espocrm root dir
        autoindex off;

        location ~* ^.+.(js|css|png|jpg|svg|svgz|jpeg|gif|ico|tpl)$ {
            access_log off;
            expires max;
        }
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
    }

    location /api/v1/ {
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^/api/v1/(.*)$ /api/v1/index.php last; break;
        }
    }

    location /portal/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /portal/index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /api/v1/portal-access {
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^/api/v1/(.*)$ /api/v1/portal-access/index.php last; break;
        }
    }

    location ~ /(\.htaccess|\web.config|\.git) {
        deny all;
    }
}

Here is a screenshot of the error
enter image description here
I hope someone can look at the configuration and tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance...
I tried modifying the root directives in the configuration as instructed by the EspoCRM Nginx Configuration guide but I could not make it work.
